# How to use ng-repeat to index a dynamically generated list of attributes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary

So I have an array of dictionaries. In the dictionaries, they have the following properties:

AttributeName
AttributeValue
ProductName

But for each dictionary, I have the property names dynamically generated. This appends an index to each property (AttributeName0, AttributeName1, etc)
The reason I do this is because I am using ui-grid, and it requires the column names to be unique in order to make a new column for each dictionary I bring in.

The dictionary looks something like this (in an array called resultsToSend):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7p4c.png)

I am trying to use ng-repeat to dynamically create a form using these dictionaries:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="result in resultsToSend">
                        <div class="col s2">

                            <md-input-container><label>{{result.AttributeName$index}}</label><input type="number" id="new-day-ARP-input" ng-model="result.AttributeName$index" /></md-input-container>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s4">
                            <label>Select {{result.ProductName$index}} Material</label>
                            <md-select ng-model="result.ProductName$index}" md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader">
                                <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
                                    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" placeholder="Search For Material..." class="demo-header-searchbox md-text">
                                </md-select-header>
                                <md-option ng-value="{{mat.ID}}" ng-repeat="mat in Materials | filter:searchTerm">{{mat.Name}}</md-option>
                            </md-select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

But I've been largely unsuccessful finding out how to use the result.(PropertyNameHere)$index to access the properties I'm trying to access.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How you are adding new attribute? by push or what?

Comment: 'var tempProductName = "ProductName" + String(k);
                        var tempAttributeName = "AttributeName" + String(k);
                        var tempAttributeValue = "AttributeValue" + String(k);
                        var tempArray = [];
                        tempArray[tempProductName] = '';
                        tempArray[tempAttributeName] = response.data[0].Attributes[k].Name;
                        tempArray[tempAttributeValue] = ''
                        $scope.resultsToSend.push(tempArray);'

Comment: You cant access **result** as a Object like : result.(PropertyNameHere)$index because result is a not available in scope there is resultsToSend exist and also result is used for looping through resultToSend so use this to access it :  **resultsToSend[$index].ProductName**

Answer (score 1):

Please use `{{result.ProductName + $index}}` in ng-model in Your md-select tag.

Comment: Ah, I tried doing that before, but I realized that if I tried to assign the ng-model like that, it throws an error "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 8 of the expression [{result.ProductName + $index] starting at [.ProductName + $index]." so I thought that it was originally the wrong way to do it.

Comment: You tried change dot for [] ? like this: {{result[ProductName] + $index}} ?

Comment: It gives me: angular.js:13920 Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'result[AttributeName] + $index' is non-assignable. Element: <input type="number" id="new-day-ARP-input" ng-model="result[AttributeName] + $index" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">